# add a space every x characters in char array in C

Tags: c

i'm making a function that given an int makes the its twos complement and convert it in a 32 bit number

the problems is that i want to  add space every 4 bits

example of the program would be "input 720, output: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 1101 0000"

i tried making the function but i don't know how to add a " " char every 4 numbers.

any ideas?

my function is:

```
char temp[32];
char* toBinary(int num) {
    int mask = 1 << (31);
    char res[39];
    for (short i = 0; i <=32; i++) {
       res[i] = (num & mask ? '1' : '0');
        num <<= 1; 
        if(i !=0 && i % 4 ==0) // push a space ;
    }
    return strcpy(temp,res);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Put a counter into your loop. After output of a digit increment the counter. If the counter is 4 reset it to 0 and print a space. There are other methods too. But yo'll need more than 32 chars for this in `temp`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky hello can you explain better? Thanks

Comment: You have twenty persons in a row in front of you. You want to give a dollar to every forth person. How would you do this? You count them 1,2,3,4 give a dollar, 1,2,3,4 give a dollar, 1,2,3,4 give a dollar etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First returning a global is *bad*. Not wrong from a C language point of view but you really have no reason to do it. The idiomatic way is to have the caller provide the char array, or if you do not need thread safety to return a static array.

Next, you need one place for the terminating null, so the size has to be 40 and not 39.

Finally, you can just iterate `for (short i=0; i<40; i++)` and add a space after every fourth character. Code could become:

```
char* toBinary(int num) {
    int mask = 1 << (31);
    static char res[40] = {0};
    for (short i = 0; i < 39; i++) {
        res[i] = (num & mask ? '1' : '0');
        num <<= 1; 
        if(i % 5 == 3) res[++i] = ' ' ;  // the trick: increment i and write a space
    }
    res[39] = '\0';   // never forget the terminating null when building a string
    return res;
}
```

Comment: This really made my day! Thanks mate! Code is perfectly working!